# StackExchange.Redis Timeout Issue

Tags: c#, redis, signalr, stackexchange.redis

We are using multiple versions of Redis Server (6.2.5 and 7.0.10 tried seperately) hosted in a Kubernetes cluster. Using default aspnet:6.0 image (bullseye). We extensively read and wrote to Redis for a while (it's been almost a year) but for 2 days we have been getting timeout errors. The error detail is below :

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout awaiting response 
(outbound=188KiB, inbound=0KiB, 37574ms elapsed, timeout is 30000ms),
 command=ZADD, next: ZADD ADQ, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 126, aw: False,
 bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 3949, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0,
 last-in: 0, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 0, async-ops: 28310, serverEndpoint: redis7.sf-app.svc:6379,
 conn-sec: 1583.67, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available,
 clientName: orchestration-317-qzp5s(SE.Redis-v2.6.96.30123), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=16,Max=1000),
 WORKER: (Busy=345,Free=32422,Min=16,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=345,QueuedItems=29523,CompletedItems=4409684),
 v: 2.6.96.30123
```

These timeouts occur in a short period that I have not measured precisely yet.
Here is the .net counters output for the running process :

```
 % Time in GC since last GC (%)                                         0
    Allocation Rate (B / 1 sec)                                      227,048
    CPU Usage (%)                                                          0
    Exception Count (Count / 1 sec)                                        0
    GC Committed Bytes (MB)                                            2,790
    GC Fragmentation (%)                                                   1.406
    GC Heap Size (MB)                                                  2,392
    Gen 0 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                                         0
    Gen 0 Size (B)                                                       384
    Gen 1 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                                         0
    Gen 1 Size (B)                                                63,191,160
    Gen 2 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                                         0
    Gen 2 Size (B)                                                 8,249,120
    IL Bytes Jitted (B)                                            1,533,858
    LOH Size (B)                                                   5,032,512
    Monitor Lock Contention Count (Count / 1 sec)                          0
    Number of Active Timers                                                9
    Number of Assemblies Loaded                                          174
    Number of Methods Jitted                                          19,209
    POH (Pinned Object Heap) Size (B)                             24,134,616
    ThreadPool Completed Work Item Count (Count / 1 sec)                  14
    ThreadPool Queue Length                                            3,611
    ThreadPool Thread Count                                              822
    Time spent in JIT (ms / 1 sec)                                         0
```

And the .net trace output :

```
1.  Threads                                                                   100%                0%
2.  (Non-Activities)                                                          99.96%              0%
3.  Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(class System.Threading.Tasks.Task&,class S    97.31%              0%
    ystem.Threading.Thread)
4.  ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(int32,value class System.Threading.Cancellat    97.06%              96.93%
    ionToken)
5.  Task.InternalWaitCore(int32,value class System.Threading.CancellationT    97.06%              0%
    oken)
6.  Task.SpinThenBlockingWait(int32,value class System.Threading.Cancellat    97.06%              0%
    ionToken)
7.  ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()                                            96.98%              0%
8.  PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()                       96.98%              0%
9.  ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(class System.Threading.    96.95%              0%
```

I have tried to increase `PoolSize` (up to 200) setting and tried to set `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`, and also tried to reduce the workload to half but none of them helped. We also use `SignalR` in the same application and we invoke redis calls in `Hub` methods (I don't know if it is related to). We intensively use commands like `zadd, zpopmin, incr, incrby` methods. All the methods we use are the async ones. As I said it's been running without problems for a while except for the last two days. Thanks for the help or any advice to diagnose the bottleneck here.